# Using Python Is there any way to copy data from one excel file to another excel file that has a different fields

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to Python and Stack Overflow. I am trying to copy data from one Excel file to another Excel file using pandas and numpy.

Let's say, the first.csv contains:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Title | Country | Status | Date | Region |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Project1 | US | Active | 09/29/20 | America |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Project2 | Brazil | Active |  | America |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Project3 | China | Active |  | Asia |

and the second.csv contains:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Title | Country | Region | Date | Status | Description |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Project1 | US | America | N/A | Active | zzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Project4 | Canada | America | N/A | Active | zzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Project5 | Africa | Africa | N/A | Active | zzz |

In the second file, the Column Status is after Date where as in first file it is after Country.
I want to copy the first.csv data to the second.csv file based on the column structure of the second.csv.

After copying I want my second.csv to look like this.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | Title | Country | Region | Date | Status | Description |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Project1 | US | America | N/A | Active | zzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Project2 | Brazil | America | N/A | Active | zzzzzzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Project3 | China | Asia | N/A | Active | zzzzzzzzzzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Project4 | Canada | America | N/A | Active | zzz |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | Project5 | Africa | Africa | N/A | Active | zzz |

Is there any way to merge/copy the file in this way in Python using numpy and pandas library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas library makes this easy. Once you have both in memory as data frames, you can just append one to the other. The append will rearrange the columns to match the first df, and just keep empty any columns in csv1_df that aren't in csv2_df.

```
csv1_df = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
csv2_df = pd.read_csv('second.csv')
combined_df = csv2_df.append(csv1_df, ignore_index=True)
combined_df.to_csv('third.csv', header=True, mode='w')
```

Comment: It kind a works.. But it created duplicate for ID 1/Project1.
I was thinking of overriding the data with second.csv file

Comment: Oh in that case you want to do an outer join... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html
`csv1_df.join(csv2_df, how='outer')`.